# This Meta has an invalid HTTPS certificate

Tags: bug

I came here for a different reason, but was welcomed with an error as follows.

[image]

Comment: And you accepted the risk and continued?! How courageous you are to risk your computer x)! I'm not sure, but I believe the certificate content could help understand what's wrong.

Comment: @Tortliena I reviewed the domains listed in the bad certificate and concluded that it's an error on SE's admins side, misconfigured certificates. But the certificates *are* SE's. This led me to deciding that it was an acceptable risk.

Comment: I was joking :) ; If the link shares a believable, well-constructed structure, and comes from an already trusted site, the risk is quite low. Certificates are more useful  when shopping, because getting hacked while paying cost a lot more than just an account or computer.

Comment: @Tortliena that's the issue with joking online - sometimes people miss it :/ That said, I'm not sure *how* to upload the certificate content here - I know how to view it, but it's several pages, each over a screen long.

Comment: Shouldn't this be addressed to SE itself? I doubt there's anything we mere pawns of SE's greed can do about this issue!

Comment: @elemtilas do you think it would be better served by posting directly to meta.SE?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I suggested! No one here in this forum, that I'm aware of, is a SE employee with the ability (authority & access to the underlying mechanism) to fix this kind of problem.

Comment: The certificate is valid for `*.meta.stackexchange.com` (third line, last domain name), which very obviously includes worldbuilding`.meta.stackexchange.com`. The problem is that you typed (probably by hand) `meta.worldbuilding` instead of the canonical `worldbuilding.meta`. (Yes, the admins should make sure that m.w.s.com does not resolve, but that is secondary -- all the clicable links provide the correct URL.)

Comment: @AlexP SE's general UX is such that, whichever site I find myself on, I have trouble finding a *link* to meta. So I often type it by hand. I was not even aware that `meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com` is *not* the canonical address.

Comment: Click on the "speech bubble" in the top-right on the top bar (that which includes the search box). A menu with all the Stack Exchange sites will drop down. The top two are the current site and its meta.

Answer (score 1):

1. This Stack and its meta site are but one of a galaxy of Stacks in the Stack Exchange network. Questions and issues about the network (security certificates are a network problem) belong on [Meta.StackExchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com), not here. Trust me, nobody who can do anything about that haunts these halls.
2. While we all wish computers were perfect and got things done in the correct order all the time, they aren't and don't. Security certificates expire. I didn't see that error when I logged on to answer your question, so it's obviously been resolved.
3. The world will not come to an end because a site you frequent and trust has a disruption with their security certificate. In fact, the site is still quite well protected. You're simply being warned that the certificate itself has become questionable — just in case it matters. An expired certificate does not mean the site is suddenly vulnerable to viruses or other forms of attack. There be no zombies here.